# Is it possible to create a script that will limit a certain programs useage of a GPU?

Tags: python

I want to create a program that allows users to limit certain programs to a maximum amount of GPU useage. EX: 90% for a game, 10% for a streaming software.

Is this at all possible?

*I understand a computer would naturally do this decently, but I want to manually do it*

Answer (score -1):

- You can use the below command to get GPU Usage
- **nvidia-smi -l 10** (windows - Later You can integrate this with python script & achieve your Task)